# Mathematical expectation of the number of transpositions in random permutation.

Tags: permutations, expectation, random

Let $P=(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n)$ be a permutation chosen randomly and equiprobably from S(n). We say that $(i, j)$ is a transposition if $p_i=j$ and $p_j=i$.
Calculate the mathematical expectation of the number of transpositions in the permutation $P$.

Let $\gamma$ be a random variable equal to the number of transpositions in the permutation.

Then $Pr(\gamma=k)$ is equal to

$Pr((\exists \; i_1,j_1,\ldots,i_k,j_k$ $(i_r,j_r)$ - transposition) and ($\forall l,s \in \bar{(1,n)} \setminus\{i_1,j_1,\ldots,i_k,j_k\}$ $(l,s)$ is not transposition)). I have problems with calculating this probability.

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}{(-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{(2!)^i}}$$ is my first guess.

Comment: That simplifies pretty easily. But is it *correct*?

Comment: @JeanMarie This is a nonstandard definition of transposition, so I don't think that applies.

Comment: I understand now what I had not understood at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_{ij}$ be a random variable which is 1 if $(i, j)$ is a transposition and 0 otherwise - that is, an indicator random variable for the event that $(i, j)$ is a transposition.  Then the expectation you want is just

$$ E \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} X_{ij} \right) $$

and by linearity of expectation, this is

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} E(X_{ij}) $$

Now you need to find $E(X_{ij})$.  This is the number of permutations $p$ of $\{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \}$ with $p_i = j, p_j = i$, divided by $n!$.  Find that numerator and do the sum.  (Hint: the sum is easy.)

Comment: Yes - basically the other $n-2$ elements can be permuted any way you want.

Comment: Hmm $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} E(X_{ij})=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \frac{(n-2)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n\cdot(n-1)}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}1=\frac{1}{n\cdot(n-1)}\frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$ It is right?

Comment: @Vlad It looks right (and confirmed by simulations I just did)

Comment: @Vlad Yes, for $n\ge2.$

Comment: @Michael Lugo The answer seems to be correct, I checked its meaning with simulation. But I am confused by the fact that in the expression $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} X_{ij} $$
does not take into account the fact that if $(i, j)$ form a transposition, then for any other $k \neq j$ $(i, j)$ does not form a transposition.In other words if $X_{ij}=1$ then $\forall k \neq j\; X_{ik}=0$. Or I do not understand something in the probabilistic model ...

Comment: @Vlad That's true, but irrelevant, because expectation is linear.  For example if we had $n = 3$ then the number of transpositions would be $X_{12} + X_{13} + X_{23}$, and each of those terms would have expectation $1/6$.  But $X_{12} = 1$ exactly if the permutation is 213, $X_{13} = 1$ exactly if the permutation is 321, and $X_{23} = 1$ exactly if the permutation is 132.  If we wanted to know more than the expectation of the number of transpositions - say we wanted to know the variance - then your concern would come into play.